# Adding OIDC support with ID4\ID3 to Legacy WebForms App

Tags: identityserver4, identityserver3

I am starting a project to link ID4 or ID3 to a number of .Net Web Applications to support SSO across them using OIDC where they vary in Technology maturity.

The one I am having some trouble with is a .Net 4.5 WebForms application which does not have OWIN support currently. I am wondering what is the best approach to integrate it with ID4 or ID3.

I have been considering doing a method such as the following but I am sure there are better ways to do this:
https://leastprivilege.com/2014/06/10/writing-an-openid-connect-web-client-from-scratch/

Regards,
Barry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Owin package, doesn't have any dependencies, so you can go straight forward and add it to your Web Forms application. This is the best/easiest approach.

Then the next thing you need is the `IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation` package (because you are using .Net Framework app).

From this point on, it doesn't matter which version of Identity Server you will choose. Both of them will be suitable for you, however I, and I'm sure many others, recommend you to use Identity Server 4.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I thought of this but as the application does not use a startup class do you have details on how to add it. Would it be in application_start I wonder?

Comment: Add the packages - Owin and Microsoft.Owin. Then add an item in the project - OWIN Startup Class. And that's it

Comment: Thanks, will try that.